# intermittent ajax failure with jquery 1.5.1, asp.net, and firefox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am lazy loading snippets of html on our page in order to improve performance. jQuery's load method does not provide access to the full ajax api (things like error callbacks) so I created a more robust version of it.

I am calling this method 3-5 times per page on just about every page load and am logging when there is some sort of error with ajax call. What I am finding is that about 0.3% of the time the ajax calls are failing the majority of the failures are in firefox 3.6. I am using jQuery 1.5.1 with ASP.NET server side. The 'errorThrown' parameter of the error callback reads:

[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders]"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"

and the jqXHR reads:

{"readyState":4,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}

I have confirmed with users that they are experienceing this problem and it's not just bots or some logging of an unexperienced error.

here is the code for my "load" widget

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.elfLoad = function (url, options) {

        return this.each(function () {

            var $elem = $(this);

            options = $.extend({}, {
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                data: "",
                error: function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {

                    $elem.html('<div class="elf-missing-content centerText">Doh! Something did not go so well when trying to load this content. Please try again later.');
                    elf.ajax.logInfo("data: " + options.data + " errorThrown: " + errorThrown + " webmethod: " + options.url + "jqXHR: " + JSON.stringify(jqXHR),"elfLoad");
                }
            }, options);

            options.success = function (data, status, jqXHR, responseText) {

                responseText = jqXHR.responseText;

                if (jqXHR.isResolved()) {

                   jqXHR.done(function (r) {
                        responseText = r;
                   });

                   $elem.html(responseText);
                }

                if (options.callback) {
                    var callbackArgs = {
                        responseText: responseText,
                        $elem: $elem,
                        status: status,
                        jqXHR: jqXHR
                    };
                    $elem.each(options.callback, [callbackArgs]);
                 }


            }

            options.url = url;

            if (options.data) {
                options.data = $.param(options.data, $.ajaxSettings.traditional);
                options.type = "POST";
            } else {
                 options.data = "";
            }

            $.ajax(options);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

A call to it would look like this $('#container').elfLoad('url.aspx',{foo:'bar'});

Has anyone else had this problem? Any ideas? jQuery claims to have recently closed a ticket that looks like this in 1.5.1 but I see someone else is having a similar issue. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8400

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by using a setTimeout for 2 seconds and retrying the request. So far this is working 100% of the time.